# terminal only running 2.7, even after changing alias

Tags: python, terminal

How can I get terminal to run a script like /manage.py where it will use python3 instead of python2?  If I type 'python' it runs python3, but this command runs python2.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: What's the first line of manage.py?

Comment: I'm using a mac, I want to be able to run a script that calls ./manage.py

Comment: what shebang  is at the top of the file?

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line of your `manage.py` should be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

This is called the shebang and tells your shell which python installation should be used based on which version of python is first in `$PATH`.

If the first line isn't `#!/usr/bin/env python3`, it should be. If it is, you should ***prepend*** the location of python3 to `$PATH`.

You'll want to do this by adding the following to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH="`which python3`:$PATH"
```

Comment: Note that if it's the manage.py from a Django project and this project uses a virtualenv, you definitly _dont_ want to mess with Python's version here.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error, it's running 2.7 when I type ./manage.py

Comment: I was but I just want my computer to do this as a whole

Comment: Edited. Try it again.

Comment: ya that works but now I would have to add that to the top of every file, is there a way to make it is it will just automatically assume python3?

Comment: You could make softlinks, but I wouldn't necessarily recommend this. If this is for django, I would recommend installing with `pip3`.